# Android In-app update API -> Immediate update problem

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-update

Started to experiment with [In-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates). Everything seems to work prefect.

But... when entering some edge cases, like for example, canceling the process of update in the process of downloading the update, the API for some reason stops working as intended.

Example: I start my activity and the first thing in onResume(), I do this:

```
//In app update code. Only works for Android 5.0 and above.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
                    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
                        try {
                            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this, 1333);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                        // If an in-app update is already running, resume the update.
                        try {
                            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,this, 1333);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
    });
 }
```

When I click on Update button and the screen for updating appears, I immediately cancel the update. It returns with onActivityResult the request code (1333) and result code (STATUS_UNKNOWN = 0) . I call finish() in that if statement, because this is a critical update that has to be updated.

The problem is now, when entering the app for the second time, onActivityResult is fired again, without showing any dialog from in-app update API and just returning the request/result code in onActivityResult callback.

Anyone with a similar problem?

Comment: Yes, I've faced the same problem few days ago. Seems like this case is not currently supported by SDK. Only thing might be helpful - you can use `registerListener (InstallStateUpdatedListener listener)` on you instance of AppUpdateManager, and listen to specific **installStatus** within the installState - int code 6 corresponds to **CANCELLED** status, which I found handy to setup alternative update flow for users

Comment: so for my immediate update is mandatory. below is my code in onActivityResult  if (requestCode == IMMEDIATE_UPDATE_APP_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //user has cancelled ask again
                showImmediateUpdateUI();
            } 
        }  but next time no update dialog is displayed. What is the alternative?

Comment: looks like there is open bug for the same issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133092990 . As per comment its Play-store issue and will be released in next w weeks.

Comment: Yea, @VanKhulup the problem is somewhere in the SDK and I don't want to go with some workaround way for my users. Mangesh, thanks for linking to the official support ticket (thought to open it myself but didn't have time).

Comment: has anyone got the solution yet for this usecase?

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is open bug for the same issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133092990 . As per comment its Play-store issue and will be released in next few weeks.